# Elasticsearch curl query sum like MySQL

Tags: mysql, curl, elasticsearch, sum, range

With MySQL, here is a simple query who works perfectly:

```
select * from table1 where field1 = 1 and field2 = 5 and field3 = 'test'
and (SELECT SUM(field4 + field5 )) between 100 and 200;
```

With Elasticsearch I'm able to make select the data with the 2 first WHERE filter but failing to make it happened with the sum/range part. Here is all details:

```
ES_HOST='http://localhost:9200'
curl -sXPUT "$ES_HOST/datas?pretty=true" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "table1": {
         "properties": {
            "field1": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "field2": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "field3": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "field4": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "field5": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPOST "$ES_HOST/datas/_bulk?pretty=true" -d'
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 1, "field2": 5, "field3":"test", "field4":100, "field5":50}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 1, "field2": 1, "field3":"test", "field4":110, "field5":50}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 1, "field2": 10, "field3":"test", "field4":105, "field5":20}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 2, "field2": 3, "field3":"test2", "field4":50, "field5":20}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 20, "field2": 13, "field3":"test3", "field4":500, "field5":220}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 50, "field2": 60, "field3":"test4", "field4":1500, "field5":120}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 50, "field2": 60, "field3":"test4", "field4":130, "field5":50}
{"index":{"_index":"datas","_type":"table1"}}
{"field1": 1, "field2": 5, "field3":"test", "field4":140, "field5":20}
'
curl -sGET "$ES_HOST/datas/_search?pretty=tarch?pretty=true"

curl -XGET "$ES_HOST/datas/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"field1":1}},{"match":{"field2":5}},{"term":{"field3":"test"}}]}}}
'
```

Any help for the sum/range part?

Comment: `select * from table1 where field1 = 1 and field2 = 5 and field3 = 'test' and (SELECT SUM(field4 + field5 ) **FROM SOMEWHERE**) between 100 and 200;` are you sure there isn't something missing from the SQL?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I missed the second select. The right query is:
select * from table1 where field1 = 1 and field2 = 5 and field3 = 'test' and (SELECT SUM(field4 + field5)) between 100 and 200 limit 10;
What about elasticsearch?

Comment: Thats the same query.  Try this instead. `select * from table1 where field1 = 1 and field2 = 5 and field3 = 'test' and (field4 + field5) between 100 and 200 limit 10` does this do what you need the query to achieve?

Comment: Regarding elasticsearch I'm not familiar, but the simpler the sql is the more likely it will work. If the query you have quoted works then it isn't good sql syntax.